# Get all the identical contracts for a given contract

Tags: evm, etherscan

I am aware of the "find similar contract" function on etherscan.io; however, it seems to only print out the top 500 identical contracts, with the time ascending order.

For instance, https://etherscan.io/find-similiar-contracts?a=0xde815ffa64c918b373d93bcb6da567a0f8134dcd&lvl=5 query could give me the top 500 matched contracts with time ascending order. But the problem is that it always start from the earliest contract, which means even if I use the most recent contract within the top 500 to **re-query**, it still shows the same thing.

So here is my question, how should I find all the identical contract, given the EVM bytecode of an online contract? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard way to do this is to 1- install a client, 2- retrieve the chain and extract the contracts, 3- store EVM code in a map and see how many addresses are using the exact same contract code.

Steps 1+2 can be a pain. But you can circumvent them very easily by working on processed chain data. Google, for instance, recently made available Ethereum mainnet data on a publicly available GCE BigTable. You can download all contract code if you need to, with metadata and json-formatted, in a matter of minutes. You can also run BigQueries without even having to download and parse anything.

Link to get you started: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics

Comment: Thank you Alex! I think that is something I am looking for.

Comment: @lllllllllllll may you share the query you wrote ?